# facebook_django : Given URL is not permitted by the application config

Tags: django, facebook, django-facebook

I'm getting this error for facebook login in local development. I'm using facebook_django package. And my dev server runs on 0.0.0.0:8000. In my site url I've tried setting my site url to 127.0.0.1:8888 and 0.0.0.0:8000 both and both ways it gives the same error

```
Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.:
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. 
It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a 
subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

Also what should be the input for App Domain field in local development ?